# Generating td elements with background color jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, background-color

I am trying to give a color to a generated td element (status of a project) but it's not working , I am getting the data but no color. How do I fix this?

Here's my code :

```
         function(data, status) {
                        var items = "";
                        data = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if (data.toString() !== "") {
                            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                                items += "<tr class='info'>";

                                if(item.STATUSPROGRESS ==="OK"){
                                    items+='<td bgcolor="#00CC66">';
                                }
                                else if(item.STATUSPROGRESS === "NOT OK"){
                                    items+="<td bgcolor='#FF0000'>";
                                }
                                else if(item.STATUSPROGRESS === "STATUS REQUIRED"){
                                    items+="<td bgcolor='#FFEC3D'>";
                                }
                                else if(item.STATUSPROGRESS === "ACTION REQUIRED FROM COMPANY"){
                                    items+="<td bgcolor='#3DB1FF'>";
                                }
                                else if(item.STATUSPROGRESS === "ACTION REQUIRED FROM CUSTOMER"){
                                    items+="<td bgcolor='#FF8B3D'>";
                                }
                                else{
                                    items+="<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";
                                }


                                items += item.PROJECTID + "</td>";
                                items += "<td>" + item.DESCRIPTION + "</td>";
                                items += "<td>" + item.CUSTOMER + "</td>";
                                items += "<td>" + item.ACCMANAGER + "</td>";
                                items += "</tr>";

                            });
                        }
                        $("#myTable tbody").append(items);
                        $("#myTable").trigger("update");



                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The  bgcolor attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead."

```
style="background-color: #3DB1FF"
```